# materializecss + Angular 6 how to configure?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, materialize

I am new to Angular in general and I am trying to use [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) 
with Angular 6. I am using CLI to create my components.

I have read materials about how to do it in Angular 2, but Angular 6 seems to be different, for instance not having angular-cli.json file.

How can I get materializecss running in Angular 6?

Command used to install materializecss:
`npm i materialize-css@next`

angular.json attempted modification:

```
           "styles": [
              "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
            ]
```

This alone did not work.

Comment: Should have read it better, you should be able to use the CLI still npm install materialize-css@next

Comment: The `angular-cli.json` file is now called `angular.json`

Comment: I'm looking for a comprehensive step by step to get them to work together. Which files do I have to change? I tried adding styles and scripts to the angular.json, but that seemed not to be enough.

Comment: I have used npm install to install materialize-css already, it is just my lack of knowledge in Angular, and how many places I have to change it.

Comment: Can you add the `angular.json` file to your question please?

Comment: Posted what I tried to add

Comment: Seems to work when I try it locally... What are you doing to check if it's worked? Did you make sure to run `ng serve` again after making your changes?

Comment: yeap, running ng serve again did the trick! For alterations of components I don't need to run it again. I guess for alterations on the angular.json I do... Thanks, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ngx-materialize](https://github.com/sherweb/ngx-materialize#installation) ?

their instructions suggests that you also need to alter the tsconfig.json file and add the following to the types array:

- "jquery",
- "materialize-css"

unless you are looking for a specific component I would suggest [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) as a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of using materialize styles in Angular.
To list some:

1. Download angular specific css frameworks-see [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for angular compatible css frameworks.
2. Download the source code from the  [materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) website and paste it into any of the components css file.
3. Download the npm package of materialize by typing npm install materialize-css@next into the terminal.

#### Note:


Some features of materialize-css require jquery. I'm currently having issues in Angular when I nmp install jquery...
materialize-css styling and colors can however still be used in components which don't require animations.

### A word on Angular specific packages:


[ngx-materialize](https://github.com/sherweb/ngx-materialize#installation) is great for easy installation,component styling and animations but has deprecated dependencies.

[materialize-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-angular) is also good, but is currently not backed by any organisations and therefore too has many out-of-date dependencies.

If you don't know exactly why you might need an angular specific css framework, consider using the vanilla Materialize or Bootstrap frameworks.